# how to get list of strings from cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have added list of interests in cloud firestore. i tried my best to get this list and display it.
I have used stream builder to fetch other fields in user collection. can somebody help me with this?

this is how collection and documents look :

[image]

this is how i used streambuilder to fetch other fields:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: myStream,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return !snapshot.hasData
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Column(
            children: [
                  DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  return Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    fit: StackFit.expand,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.65,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                            end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                            colors: [
                              Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.0),
                              Colors.black,
                            ],
                            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                toBeginningOfSentenceCase(
                                        '${document.data()['username']}') +
                                    ',  ' +
                                    '${document.data()['age']}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 40,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
```

Comment: Wich fileds, what error you get ?

Comment: i have displayed username and age fields using text widget, but i have no idea of can i get list of interets field.

Comment: ho do you want to shw them in on text or ?

Comment: yeah in simple text widget.. i tried this: Text( '$ document.data()[ 'interets' ] ,'). This is showing result in brackets like this : [ Food, Life, Biking ]. I text with without brackets.